# How do I clear a required field value - reverts back to last valid value

Tags: validation, converters, jsf-2.2

I have an input field on my facelet with a custom converter (to whatever other object, just another string in my example) as well as a custom validator ("required" value, amongst other checks). Here is a use case describing expected, and the problematic actual, steps:

1. Enter a valid value and blur field (tab out or click on other element).

   - The converter changes the field value to a normalized string representation of the object. **as expected**
2. Go back and enter an invalid value, blur again.

   - Validation message shows error.  **as expected**
   - Field value stays at the invalid value. **as expected**
3. Go back and delete value, blur again.

   - Validation message shows error.  **as expected**
   - The field value changes back to the last valid (normalized) value. ***NOT AS EXPECTED, want it to stay empty***

*It is a bit counter-intuitive if the validation message shows that a value should be supplied, while the old valid value shows. Any idea what I can do to have the field stay clear even if the validation fails?*

I perhaps need to emphasise the following about the converter:

- null/empty strings are converted to the null object. (But the validator requires a valid non-null value.)
- An ajax call on `blur` is employed to always run the converter when done typing in the value - the intention is that the supplied value is converted to the object of the backing bean member, then converted back to a ("normalized") string representation of the object. ("Normalization" examples: conforming to the enum constant name's case, or being in a certain date format.)

I'm using JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.7) on GlassFish 4.1.

Sample code (pruned back considerably to just show a test case, but contains the important parts - I think):

**Backing bean:**

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    :
    private String test; // plus g/setters
    :
}
```

**JSF view page:**

```xml
<h:form>
    :
    <h:inputText id="test" binding="#{test}" value="#{testBean.test}">
        <cp:uppercaseConverter />
        <f:validator binding="${testValidator}" />
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="@this msg_test" /><!-- @this forces converter on blur -->
    </h:inputText>
    <h:messages id="msg_test" for="test" />
    :
</h:form>
```

**Custom converter:** (Remember, somewhat artificial for testing purposes)

```java
/**
 * The "object" as used in the backing bean is simply the uppercase version of
 * the input value in the field.
 */
@FacesConverter("UppercaseConverter")
public class UppercaseConverter implements Converter, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(
        FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, String newValue
    ) throws ConverterException {
        if (newValue == null || newValue.trim().equals(""))
            return null;
        return newValue.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(
        FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object value
    ) throws ConverterException {
        if (value == null) return "";
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

**Custom validator:** (Remember, somewhat artificial for testing purposes)

```java
/**
 * Values are valid only if they start with an "A" (not case sensitive).
 * Thus, null or empty values are also invalid implicitly.
 */
@ManagedBean
@FacesValidator
public class TestValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(
        FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value
    ) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null || !value.toString().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith("a"))
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("A value starting with A or a is required"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously caused by the `<f:ajax>` call that also `render`s `@this`, together with the message element.

Rendering `@this` causes the converter to run and show the **converted** value in the field (however this can't be done for an invalid or empty value, obviously).

I think the simplest workaround for now is to remove the `@this` from the `render` attribute. The result will have only a slight aesthetic drawback which is not the end of the world - much less severe (confusing the user) in my opinion than having an "this is invalid" message showing on a valid and previously entered and overwritten value.